# Laravel: Return attribute from a relation and not the entire object

Tags: php, api, laravel, eloquent, relation

I'm developing and API with Laravel, but I have a problem or question with relations  1:N  (one to many). Is there posible to only show one attribute just like this, where `creatorUser` is my relation.

```
{
      "id": "string",
      "production": "string",
      "title": "string",
      "description": "string",
      "resourceType": "string",
      "collections": "string",
      "creatorUser: "name"
}
```

creatorUser is my relation and at this moment i'm getting like this

```
{
      "id": "string",
      "production": "string",
      "title": "string",
      "description": "string",
      "resourceType": "string",
      "collections": "string",
      "creatorUser: {
         id:  "string",
         name: "string"
        }
}
```

I don't want to retrieve the data from creatorUser like object, just the name and be showed like this    `"creatorUser: "name"` Is there any way?

and I'm retrieving my info like this (This is my controller)

```
  return CTL_Resource::with(['creationCountry' => function ($query) {
           $query->select('idCountry', 'name');
         }, 'creatorUser' => function ($query) {
           $query->select('idUser', 'name');
         }, 'resourceType' => function ($query) {
           $query->select(['idResourceType', 'name']);
         }, 'tags' => function ($query) {
           $query->select(['idTag' => 'name']);
         }, 'quickTags' => function ($query) {
           $query->select(['idQuickTag' => 'name']);
         }, 'relatedTo' => function ($query) {
           $query->select(['idRelatedTo' => 'name']);
         }])->orderBy('createTime', 'DESC')->paginate($request->per_page);
```

thanks for help.
(don't ask why id's are string, hahaha, its because they are UUIDs) :P

Answer (score 1):

Inside of the model that is called by creatorUser.. `"App\User"` .. use the protected variable `$hidden` set as an array and pass the field name (or attribute name) into the array to hide the id of that model in the json return object...

So for example:

Say I have a model named Foo and inside of the Foo model I have this getting returned:

```
{
    foo_order: 039,
    foo_id: 12982,
    foo_name: "Bar"   
}
```

In this example I want to get rid of, or hide, `foo_id` from the returned json object. Then inside of my `"App\Foo"` model I'd simple add in:

```
namespace app;

use whatever\goes\here;

class FooModel extends Model
{ 
    ...
    ...
    /*
    * Hide the listed fields (Attributes) 
    * from the returned json object
    */
    protected $hidden = array('foo_id');
}
```

the result **SHOULD** be the following when you "get" results from this specific table/model:

```
{
    foo_order: 039,
    foo_name: "Bar"   
}
```

For more information on a deeper level to modify your returned json results please review the following doc:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators